# how to combine fxml file with 3d Box and PerspectiveCamera

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, fxml

As a newbie I'm trying to do some my own projects to practice Java, JavaFX and Raspberry coding. Ma latest goal which I set for myself is 3D visualization of force from tensometric beam. I managed to achieve simple chart and and simple visualization of actual pressure force (in circle).
(https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2663/spBwMs.gif)
Now I'd like to represent it as 3D bar. 
I tried to understood some examples from Ensemble: jnlps://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/8/samples/Ensemble/Ensemble.jnlp 
and I managed to do something like that:
(https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/2766/12te0a.gif)
but I'd like to achieve something similar using FXML file.

I tried to code it but no effect so far. I'd like you use some Hbox to place 2 boxes next to each other, but then I don't know where to place Camera properly. Actually 3D with javaFX is a little bit of black magic for me ;)

Main.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,800, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Controller{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;
    @FXML
    private Box box;
    @FXML
    private PerspectiveCamera camera;


    final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

    private Timeline animation;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {


        box.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.ORANGE));
/*      box.setDepth(100);
        box.setWidth(100);
        box.setHeight(100);*/
        rx.setAngle(90);
        ry.setAngle(25);
        box.getTransforms().addAll(rz, ry, rx);

        animation = new Timeline();
        animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,

                        new KeyValue(box.depthProperty(), 0d),
                        new KeyValue(box.translateYProperty(),400d)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5),

                        new KeyValue(box.depthProperty(), 800d),
                        new KeyValue(box.translateYProperty(), 0d)));

        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        camera.getTransforms().addAll (
                new Rotate(-35, Rotate.X_AXIS),
                new Translate(0, 0, 10)
        );

        box.sceneProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                box.getScene().setCamera(camera);
                box.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
        });
        animation.play();
    }

}
```

main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Box?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="check.brakes.Controller">
   <children>
      <Box fx:id="box" depth="100.0" height="100.0" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="673.0" width="100.0">

            </Box>
      <PerspectiveCamera fx:id="camera" farClip="70.0" fieldOfView="35.0" nearClip="0.5" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I expect the bars should look like from the example I provided.

**Update**

I did it, I'm sure it's not perfect at all, but somehow I have to start.

BTW.

Why is that, when i resize application window, camera angle is changing ?

Comment: You should have a read at how FXML [works](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) first. There are some important issues to solve in your code: `Controller` **shouldn't** extend from `Application` and it shouldn't have a `start` method. You should set `fx:controller` in your `main.fxml` file. And the `subScene` node is not added to the scene graph, so it won't show up...

Comment: thank you for reply.
So I made corrections according to your tips. Now I can see the box (at least part of it), but camera still doesn't work even when I added it to fxml. I removed subScene cause I think it's not needed there for now.

Comment: I've found one of yours solutions you gave to some other user, and It has helped me too:

 pane.sceneProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                pane.getScene().setCamera(camera);
                pane.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
        });

before that I was putting only this line:   pane.getScene().setCamera(camera); and it didn't work, although it was in fxml, why is that? 
so at the moment i'm quite close :)